# suggest some job scheduler or third party tool in java web application

Tags: java

We are developing a web application using java,jsp,Apache server.

I need a requirement to run a scheduler dynamically to generate reports whenever the given condition fails.pls suggest any jobschedulers

Answer (score 1):

quartz -> http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

(it used to be part of open symphony but the url changed now)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/).

It is open source and can be integrated with any type of Java application.